# Javascript function not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

On JQuerys's page (http://api.jquery.com/submit/) I am trying out one of their examples. It's pure copy paste but (except, html, body, etc.) Still it doesn't work. What is the problem:

```
<body>
<html>
<head>
<script>

$('#target').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});

</script>

</head>

<form id="target" action="get_input_values.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I just want to have a function that can be triggered when I submit a form. Next step I will need to get the values from the input fields.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to attach the submit event to the form once the form has loaded on the page.

To do this you can wrap the whole thing in a `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#target').submit(function() {
      alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
      return false;
   });
});
```

This is basically saying that once the document has finished loading, go and find the form and attach a submit event to it. Trying to do this the way you did it runs the risk that the form on the page won't have loaded by the time your Javascript tried to find it.

Here's a working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/MmMa8/

Comment: Thank you, it was part of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't wrapped your script in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

block, so the element `#target` can't be found when your code is run.

Comment: ...which is necessary because the code to bind the `submit` handler is before the definition of the element being bound to.  Reversing the order (so that the `<script>` is after the `<form>`) would also work.

Answer (score 3):

There is no element with the id `target` in the DOM **at the time the script runs**. As a result, zero elements have the submit event handler attached.

Move the script to the end of the document (just before `</body>`)

Answer (score 1):

Did you load the jQuery?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Of course, forgot that one. Thanks! Also, need to put the function in .ready.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is wrong. It should be sequenced as:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But your JavaScript is not working because you have to put it inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code
});
```

and additionally you have to include jQuery at the beginning:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and wrap it inside document.ready or like below

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#target').submit(function() {
 alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
 return false;
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `<script>...</script>` in the end. Or wrap the `submit` function on `ready()` function like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#target').submit(function() {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    return false;
  });
});
```

This way the `submit` will be bind to the form after the whole page is been loaded.